# Edit history in Neovim

Tags: neovim, command-history

I'd like to edit my command history at `~/.local/share/nvim/shada/main.shada` to remove some incorrect commands.

I open the file with `nvim main.shada`, remove the commands in question, and close the file.

Yet, when I start another instance of Neovim, I can see that the old incorrect commands are still there. I assume that when closing main.shada the command history in memory, still containing the deleted commands, was written to main.shada.

Is there a way I can disable command history temporarily in order to edit Neovim's history?

Comment: How about `nvim -i NONE`?

Comment: I think in Vim I usually `call histdel()`, then `:wviminfo!`